# Can I bind directly to SQLite table?

Tags: .net, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

I have a Xamarin app on Android. There is SQLite database using sqlite-net-pcl nuget. It has table `Items`.

Can I bind directly to it eg `list.ItemsSource = Database.Items` so the changes in the table are reflected automatically in the list?

Since sql-lite-pcl is ORM - it should be possible theoretically..

Comment: Well, you can bind it that way but it will need to be an observable collection for it to work best, Secondly, make sure that every time you open that view(where you show all items) that the Items are fetched from the database. But if what you want is you bind it once with the database and it should update all by itself then I do not think it will until you refetch.

Comment: the question is exactly - how to do it without "re-fetch".. also there is no such thing as `Database.Items`.. I wrote it just as an idea..

Comment: Well, then you have your answer there is no direct way!!!

Comment: @Boppity As FreakyAli said,we usually get sqlite data into List collection, then binding this collection to ListView, like this:https://xamarinmonkeys.blogspot.com/2019/02/xamarinforms-sqlite-database-crud.html

Comment: thats not what I am asking. in terms of xaml you might call it onetime binding and I am talking about oneway binding.. if that's easier to understand.

Comment: @BoppityBop If you want to bind one sqlite table to ListView, As FreakyAli's said that I think it is impossible. The source need to Collection, not table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the consensus here is that it is not possible. I asked on the GitHub to implement it though there was no response for a week.

I would probably write a wrapper myself and post it here later.

But as it stands at the moment the answer is - **no**